# Как задать toolbar для подэкранов меню настроек (Preferences)

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar

[Нашел в интернете инструкцию о подэкранах меню настроек](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings?hl=ru#Subscreens)

сделал, получилось так:

[image: Основное меню настроек]
[image: Подэкран основного меню настроек]

Необходимо на каждом из подэкранов сделать тот же toolbar что и в основном меню.

> Settings Activity

```
package ru.test;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.DrawableCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        setTheme(R.style.Light);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);

        // вставка toolbar
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // вставка кнопки назад + manifest

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        // вывод на toolbar названия текущего меню
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Settings");

        // вставка фрагмента, с условиями
        if(findViewById(R.id.fragment_container)!=null)
        {
            if(savedInstanceState!=null)
                return;

            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container,new SettingsFragment()).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

> Settings Fragment

```
package ru.test;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.preference.SwitchPreference;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    public SwitchPreference night_modePref;
    private boolean isNightModeEnabled = false;

    // инициализация preferences в SettingsFragment
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
}
```

> preferences.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <PreferenceScreen
        android:key="settings_personalization_key"
        android:title="@string/settings_personalization_title"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_personalization"
        android:summary="@string/settings_personalization_summary">

        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="key11"
            android:title="title11"/>
    </PreferenceScreen>

    <PreferenceScreen
        android:key="settings_editor_key"
        android:title="@string/settings_editor_title"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_editor"
        android:summary="@string/settings_editor_summary">

        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="key21"
            android:title="title21"/>
    </PreferenceScreen>

    <PreferenceScreen
        android:key="settings_data_key"
        android:title="@string/settings_data_title"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_data"
        android:summary="@string/settings_data_summary">

        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="key31"
            android:title="title31"/>
    </PreferenceScreen>

    <PreferenceScreen
        android:key="settings_about_key"
        android:title="@string/settings_about_title"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_about"
        android:summary="@string/settings_about_summary">
        <intent
            android:action="ru.test.AboutActivity">
        </intent>
    </PreferenceScreen>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

> toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:id="@+id/toolBar">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

> settings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SettingsActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        >
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: И что мешает скопировать в другие активити строчки, добавляющие тулбар?

Comment: Settings Activity то одно....
в нем Settings Fragment, в нем settings.xml в нем toolbar и preferences.xml.
переключение идет за счет PreferenceScreen

Я так понимаю нужно добавить тот же код на обновление фрагмента
типа в onResume или что-то подобное,
подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Не знаю, честно говоря. А это точно тулбар, а не часть первого экрана/фрагмента?

Comment: в том коде что выше все есть.....